# Object variable or with block variable not set - error '91'

Tags: vba, excel

```
    Sub Two()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "http://example.com/market/listings/578080/Sneakers%20(WHITE)"
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
Srd27 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("market_commodity_orders_header_promote")(0).innerText
ActiveSheet.Range("D27").Value = Srd27

IE.Navigate "http://example.com/market/listings/578080/Floral%20Shirt%20(Black)"
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
Srd28 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("market_commodity_orders_header_promote")(0).innerText
ActiveSheet.Range("D28").Value = Srd28

IE.Navigate "http://example.com/market/listings/578080/Tracksuit%20Top%20(Yellow)"
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
Srd29 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("market_commodity_orders_header_promote")(0).innerText
ActiveSheet.Range("D29").Value = Srd29

IE.Navigate "http://example.com/market/listings/578080/School%20Jacket"
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
Srd30 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("market_commodity_orders_header_promote")(0).innerText
ActiveSheet.Range("D30").Value = Srd30

IE.Navigate "http://example.com/market/listings/578080/Leather%20Bootcut%20Pants"
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
Srd31 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("market_commodity_orders_header_promote")(0).innerText
ActiveSheet.Range("D31").Value = Srd31

    IE.Quit
    End Sub
```

If i use <kbd>F8</kbd> key in Visual Basic app it works sometimes. But when I use macros in Excel its saying

> 'object variable or with block variable not set - error '91''

Comment: On what line? which piece of code gives you the problem?  Use `Option Explicit` and declare your variables.

Comment: `Srd27` up to `Srd31` are objects, you need to use the `Set` keyword e.g. `Set Srd27 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it and from what I can see it's that the address "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/578080/Sneakers%20(WHITE)" gives you a page saying that the product could not be found. 
The method getElementsByClassName generates error because the element you are looking for is not available on the loaded page.

Try something like this:

```
       Sub Two()
```

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/578080/Sneakers%20(WHITE)"
Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4
on error resume next
Srd27 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("market_commodity_orders_header_promote")(0).innerText
on error goto 0
If Srd27 <> "" then
   ActiveSheet.Range("D27").Value = Srd27
Else
   ActiveSheet.Range("D27").Value = "Product not found"
end if

'repeat for the rest of the code

`IE.Quit
End Sub`

And of course I am always encouraging to use Option Explicit and declare all variables.

Comment: i tried it with correct link but it says Product not found.

'repeat for the rest of the code'. it not pass to second one. its stuck at one. when i use f8 its passing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the object and validate its state before trying to access its properties.

**getElementsByClassName()**

> Returns a collection of objects with the same class attribute value.

```
Sub Two()

    Dim IE As Object, Srd27 As Object

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/578080/Sneakers%20(WHITE)"
    Do: DoEvents: Loop Until IE.ReadyState = 4

    Set Srd27 = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("market_commodity_orders_header_promote")(0)

    If Not Srd27 Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("D27").Value = Srd27.innerText
    End If
End Sub
```

### Edit:

To get multiple results, you have to loop through the elements collection and get the innerText of each element.

```
Dim elements As Object, element as Object

Set elements = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("market_commodity_orders_header_promote")

If Not elements Is Nothing Then
    For Each element in elements
        Debug.Print element.innerText
    Next
End if
```

Comment: it works well for single but if i try to get multiple result, it did not show result of second one, three,four ...

Comment: You need to loop through the elements collection. See edit.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I am sorry :(

Comment: why is it working when i open vba and pres F8 ? when i use macro in excel it's not working